# I am working on specific website not able to find locator using selenium automation

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium with c# here i am not able to find locator in automation on latest chrome(112+ chrome version) browser using automation, and below 112 chrome version its working fine.

I tried with different waits, different locator but not able to resolve this issue could you please help me out for this issue...

Comment: Can you explain more? Which element are you trying to located and what locator did you try?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.